# Electric shock in water

Tags: charger, telephone

In my country, someone died recently due to an electric shock when their smartphone fell in a bathtub. I'm trying to understand what's going on the charger side when a poor quality cable used to charge the phone accidentally falls into the water.

The press article say :

*The device was in charge, explains the regional daily which recalls that a young had suffered the same fate in December when her cell phone fell in the water.*

Comment: How does that explain why the residual current device didn't trip? How does that explain why the charger failed short circuit internally? An explanation requires evidence / analysis of the failures that led to this fatality.

Comment: @Andyaka, I have no idea about this but the press article specifies that the electrical installation was not damaged and correct. But this is specified : "
The latter was connected to a cable in poor condition and plugged into an electrical outlet."

Comment: If you have no idea about what I mentioned then there's little point trying to invent any theory about this.

Comment: @Andyaka, yes thank you I'm thinking about that.

Comment: Take a look at this video of Electroboom: https://youtu.be/SHGo-52wCDc?t=70 (1:10)

Comment: Which country? Do they use / require / fit rcd’s?

Comment: @Andyaka, What interests me is what happens at the charger if the smartphone falls into the water or the poor quality cable falls soaked in water.

Comment: @SolarMike, The country is France. Sorry I don't know about "rcd's"

Comment: Rcd is what Andy referred to Residual Current Device...

Comment: Did they have a mains lead with the charger that fell in the water?

Comment: @SolarMike, yes exactly.

Comment: So it’s not a smartphone that electrocuted them...

Comment: @SolarMike, Sorry , charger does not seem to have fallen in water, only the phone joined to a poor quality wire.

Comment: If it's a typical USB-type charger, my theory would be that it was plugged into an extension cord that fell into the tub.  It might also be a freak lightning incident.  But I can't imagine 5V killing anybody, even in a bathtub.

Comment: The primary insulation is a small ferrite transformer with magnet wire being pulsed at high frequency to step down to rectifier and a regulated 5Vdc. This usually rated for 3 to 4kV impulse isolation. Meters have 6kV arc gaps.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because so far, too less information is provided, which leads to only speculations and makes this "question" (what is the question anyway?) unanswerable.

Comment: If the connector was USB-C, it can provide up to 20V/100W (5A), which is probably enough to kill you...

Comment: @RonBeyer No it is not, to make a significant (i.e. heart stopping) current flow, a high enough voltage is needed, like more than 50 to 100 V. The human skin is quite high-resistance so at low voltages, not enough current is going to flow. The high voltage is needed to make enough current flow despite the high resistance. USB connectors aren't shielded/protected like mains connectors are that's because there's no need as the voltage is low enough.

Comment: @RonBeyer, you would have to separate the two wires in the charging cable and place them on opposite sides of a person's body .... a person could not get electrocuted by current flowing over a distance of 10 mm ... perhaps a small burn could occur

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dangerous mains voltage should only be present on the live contact of the mains socket. The earth contact should have a low or zero voltage so that it is safe to touch. As the installation was deemed correct we can assume that the earth contact was properly connected.

It is the task of the **charger** to separate the (dangerous) mains voltage from harming the (human) user.

The charging cable only conducts the **safe** (mains isolated) low voltage to the phone. The cable should have no unsafe connection to the mains as the **charger** must take care of the isolation from the mains.

The phone connects to the cable so the same that is true for the cable is true for the phone, it should not have any unsafe connection to mains power.

So my conclusion is that the **charger** must have been faulty and/or is of a type that did not provide enough **mains isolation** and/or was getting **too humid**. In the manual of the charger it usually states that the charger should not be used under very humid conditions.

On a good (and dry) charger, you can touch the low voltage (USB) output as much as you like using your fingers or a broken cable and **nothing** should happen.

On top of that you would need to be quite unlucky to get shocked in such a way that you (immediately?) die.

Comment: Indeed, I routinely stick the phone end of my charger on my tongue to see if it is producing any output when the phone doesn't react to me plugging it in.. I can't absolutely confirm that it has had no deleterious affects on my brain function though :)

Comment: Thank you for your opinion and informations.

Comment: @CaiusJard, have you had any problems with corrosion on the connector as a result of putting saliva on the contacts?

Comment: *Or* the person tried to unplug the charger with wet hands and got water in the socket. Maybe. Or they got water in the charger. Maybe. It's still a bad idea to bring electronics into the bath because you might break the electronics.